# S02E23 Flash Earth 3 [Spoiler Alert]

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Last week Episode 23 of Season 2 of Flash (2014) TV Series released.
When I was watching it, near the end Flash is racing Zoom.
Then Zoom says "Earth 1 is the center of the multiverse, it's THE access point to the other earths".

And than at the end Wells and Jesse go to Earth 2, to bring Jay Garrick to Earth 3.

Is this a design flaw? or did Zoom lie?

Comment: Note that Zoom visited many Earths before Earth-1, that he visited for the first time after the singularity between E-1 and E-2 was created in the Season 1 finale. Therefore, it is probably possible to go to E-3 from E-2.

Comment: @Taladris I don't remember if it was ever stated explicitly, but I got the impression E-2 Zoom kidnapped E-3 Jay prior to visiting E-1, in which case it almost certainly is possible.

Comment: @DavidH: I had a slight doubt about this, so I edited my comment to add probably haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Neither. It's just a matter of Wells and Quick being willing to help figure out how to get Garrick home, but wanting to do the work on Earth 2.

> Jay: Now all I have to do is find my way home.
>
> Cisco: And where's that?
>
> Jay: I think you would call it Earth-3.
>
> Cisco: Uh-huh. Well, I can get you to Earth-2.
>
> Wells: My daughter and I can help you with the rest.
>
> Jesse: We can?
>
> Wells: Yes, we can. We're going home.

Cisco doesn't know how to get Jay home, but Wells and his daughter are going to give it a shot. Given that Wells was instrumental in figuring out the portals, this isn't a bad idea. If it means having to come back to Earth-1 to do so in the end, it's physically possible to do so. In the meantime, Jesse was very eager to go back to Earth-2, and Wells seems ready to go as well.

Comment: Still they need Cisco to create a portal Earth-1, to create one to Earth-3, I would think they had enough resources + Cisco etc. to help them!

Comment: Possibly, but not necessarily. Wells understands a lot about the portals and may be able to figure out how to open them himself (clearly his hope/intention based on this scene).

Answer (score 0):

What's interesting tho is Zoom mentions that like in the comics, Earth-1, Barry's Earth, is the lynchpin to the others, which suggests that it would be easier to travel from one to the other from there.

Most likely the more advanced technology of Earth-2 would make the research of the trip easier.

Also, I think we can all agree that since the show's Earth-2 is not that similar to the one(s) from the comics, their Earth-3 is not similar either.  Cause in the comics, all the heroes are villains, which would mean Jay is likely an even bigger Baddie that Zoom.

I'm holding out hope (and so is Shipp, based on his interviews) that Jay's Earth is the same one that the surprise character came from at the end of Legends of Tomorrow.

Comment: Honestly, the show's Earth-2 always seemed a bit like Earth-3, in that everyone we saw was in fact a bad guy. Yes, some of those sent from Earth-2 to Earth-1 by Zoom apparently did what they did due to coercion; but, some Earth-1 heroes (Black Canary and Deathstorm) are clearly "bad" on Earth-2. So, the show's "Earth-3" may turn out to be more like DC's Earth-2, with a heroic age that started much sooner, and older heroes due to that fact.